# grails build an array with json builder

Tags: json, grails

I use this code to build an array of employees:

```
render(((new JsonBuilder())
        {
            'all' employees.collect { Employee employee ->
                [
                        id: employee.id,
                        name: employee.firstName + " " + employee.lastName
                ]
            }.sort() { it.name }
        }) as JSON)
```

the result is:

```
"{
    all: [
       {id: 1, name: "balh blah"},
       ...
    ]
}"
```

but I want a json of an array without the "all" field, like this:

```
"[
       {id: 1, name: "balh blah"},
       ...
 ]"
```

How can I achieve that?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you tried removing the 'all' part (line 3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need a JSonBuilder, if you have what you need in a collection, just return the collection as JSON.

```
def employee = Employee.findAll()
render employee as JSON
```

UPDATE:
tried myself with the following code:

```
def  userList = User.list(params)
def all = userList.collect {User user ->
  [id: user.id,
  name : user.firstName + " " + user.lastName]
}.sort() { it.name }

render all as JSON
```

Comment: as you can see in my code I customize the structure of the object, that why I'm using json builder. what you did wont help me to customize the object and I want to use json builder and not the register marsheler

Comment: @Noampz, just updated my post with the code that worked for me.